# Uploading files with jquery's .post

Tags: php, post, file-upload, jquery

I have form that uploads file's perfectly, with a post-page-refresh-form.

However I have ajaxiefied the form with jquery's $.post

All of the data except for the file upload is saving nicely.

Is there somthing special I need to do to the form or in jquery to get the upload to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot upload with javascript (it would mean granting js file access on your computer, a no go from security standpoint). [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) has a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree with Wrikken about Uloadify being a great solution.

But, yes, Javascript does not have access to upload files. There is a way around this by using Flash, but I would not go through all the trouble to build it yourself when there are other plugins out there that will take care of it all for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it "lookalike" AJAX.
Use a hidden iframe and send your form into this iframe, you will be able to observe the onload of the iframe and get a response.

This way gives you also the option for an easy fallback if JS is disabled.

Comment: We used to use this indeed back in the good ol' days, but an upload form to a hidden iframe may be non-javascript, it is not really user-friendly to let them upload stuff without _any_ possibility to tell them that the upload failed, finished, whatever. That is what it would be like with no javascript (terrible confusing to users although it works).

Comment: You are wrong, it's very easy to leave anybody satisfied. Take a form and send this to _self-window(the NO-JS-way). With JS you only have to create the iframe and change the form's target-window to the iframe: anybody will be happy and able to get a response.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood / misread, I though you were claiming a hidden iframe as a non-js way, my apologies.